# Admob banner not showing in real devices

Tags: android, admob, ads, adsense

after 2 weeks of my App in Google store i have realized that Banner is not showing in real devices. When i was testing it with Android studio virtual device, it was fine.

This the code related to banner in my MainActivity:

```
AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(request);
```

and Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/gray_background">
    <com.flaviofaria.kenburnsview.KenBurnsView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:context="misc.songbox.Search"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView

            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/bannerAd">

        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `AdView` should be on uppermost layer

Comment: What do u mean?

Answer (score 1):

Use this xml code...

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView

        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/bannerAd">

    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Comment: Do you think its the reason?

Comment: yes this is also reason, first run your this app 5 screen size and run also in 4 screen size then u will come to know

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to load test ads but not live ads, it sounds like an issue with your AdMob account. Can you make sure that you properly set up a payment system and/or verified your PIN? If they are not done, then live ads would not be served from your account.

Comment: Thanks but thats not a problem since my interstitial ads are workig and showing ads. But some devices no banner is shown. Its kind of making me very nerveous since i have no solution and dont know what to do.